# Push notification token not received on iOS 8. Works fine on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have problems with receiving push notification token. My app is behaving in a strange way I never encountered before.

App supports iOS 7.0+ and this is how I register to push notifications:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
    }
    ...
}
```

On iOS 7 everything works fine. App displays alert to the user. If the user approves notifications, the app gets token and all is OK.
On iOS 8 app doesn't received push notification token. App displays alert to the user, but when user approves nothing happens. App doesn't received `application: didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` or `application: didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` calls.